# How to get file descriptor from inputstream in android

Tags: android

I am loading a number of images in application using BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor.But decodeFileDescriptor wants filedescriptor.decodeFileDescriptor as the argument.I want to load image from assets.So I am using asset manager to get path to asset folder.I know that I can get filedescriptor through fileinputstream.But return type of asset manager open method is input stream so I have to use inputstream.Even I cannot find a way to get fileinputstream from inputstream.So How do I get filedescriptor from inputstream.Thanks for help

Comment: What is wrong with the `decodeStream()` method on `BitmapFactory`?

Comment: I am getting out of memory exception while using decodestream as I have to load a lot of image for animation.I have read that for many images one should use BitmapFactory.decodefiledescriptor.

Comment: Since an asset is merely an entry in a ZIP archive, I will be rather surprised if there is a way to get a `FileDescriptor` for it. Beyond that, I will be **very** surprised if this matters at all in terms of your memory usage.

Comment: I am getting this error for memory out of exception                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: That is because you do not have a big enough block of memory for whatever it is that you are trying to do. This is common when dealing with lots of bitmaps, regardless of where the bitmaps come from. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/115145) is about the only one on that question that is worthwhile on its own. Some of the others have useful tidbits (e.g., `inBitmap`, `inSampleSize` on `BitmapFactory.Options`). I delivered [a presentation at the Samsung Developer Conference](http://commonsware.com/videos) last year that covers memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You should use openFd instead.Something like this.

```
    AssetFileDescriptor blah = mainActivity.getResources().getAssets().openFd("acme.png");
    FileDescriptor fd =  blah.getFileDescriptor();
```

Hope it helps!